# Convert Decimal to Hex and place a starting zero if the conversion results in a single hex letter (Bash)

Tags: bash, openssl, hex, vpn, openvpn

Here's my case scenario...

I'm writing a bash script to verify all my VPN certificates and check if any of them is expired.
VPN certificates (**.crt** files) usually have associated private-keys (**.pem** files). Those **.crt** files have an unique integer serial number written in them, and the **.pem** files are named based on the conversion of this serial number to hexadecimal.

Example:

- A certificate **john.crt** has a unique serial number written inside it, let's say it is **44**.
- **44** in hexadecimal is **2C**. So the **.pem** file associated to **john.crt** will be named **2C.pem**.

To verify if a certificate has expired I use this command:

```
openssl verify -CAfile /etc/openvpn/keys/my-organization/ca.pem /etc/openvpn/keys/my-organization/xx.pem
```

So I need to know the serial number that's inside the certificates and convert them to hexadecimal to know the name of all **.pem** files.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

serial_numbers=(`cat /etc/openvpn/keys/my-organization/*.crt | grep "Serial Number" | awk '{print $3}'`)

for number in ${serial_numbers[*]}; do
    toHex=(`echo "obase=16; $number" | bc`)

    for item in ${toHex[*]}; do
        verify=(`openssl verify -CAfile /etc/openvpn/keys/my-organization/ca.pem /etc/openvpn/keys/my-organization/"$item".pem`)

        for line in ${verify[*]}; do
            echo $line
        done
    done
done
```

This works, but for some I get **no such file or directory**...
Some serial numbers, when converted to hexadecimal, result in a single letter. In that case, the **.pem** files should have a starting **0** (zero) on their names.

Example:

- **will.crt** has **15** as it's serial number.
- **15** in hexadecimal is **F**. So the **.pem** file associated to **will.crt** should be named **0F.pem**.

How can I get passed this and make it work for every case?

Comment: The arrays `toHex` and `verify` only ever contain a single element, no?

Comment: No, serial_numbers contains all **.crt** files in that folder, so there's at least 40 elements in each array!

Comment: But after `for number in ${serial_numbers[*]}`, `number` is a scalar, and the assignment `toHex=(\`echo "obase=16; $number" | bc\`)` results in `toHex` containing just one element – could be `toHex=$(echo "obase=16; $number" | bc)` instead.

Comment: Don't know what I'm missing but here it works! This script is in my work computer, tomorrow I'll check it and confirm if I pasted it wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use formatting with `printf`:

```
$ printf '%02X\n' 15 44
0F
2C
```

`%X` is hex with uppercase characters, and `02` is zero-padding to at least a width of 2.

You can replace this statement

```sh
toHex=(`echo "obase=16; $number" | bc`)
```

with

```sh
printf -v toHex '%02X' "$number"
```

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin! I managed to figure it out doing something similar, but your way is even better!